# Jersey 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have been trying since hours to correct http error `415 Unsupported Media Type` but it is still showing media unsupported page. 
I am adding headers `application/json` in Postman.

Here is my Java Code

```
package lostLove;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response; 

import org.json.JSONObject;


@Path("/Story") 
public class Story {

      @POST
      @Consumes({"application/json"})
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    //  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    //  @Path("/Story") 
      public JSONObject sayJsonTextHello(JSONObject inputJsonObj) throws Exception {

        String input = (String) inputJsonObj.get("input");
        String output = "The input you sent is :" + input;
        JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
        outputJsonObj.put("output", output);

        return outputJsonObj;
      }

      @GET  
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)  

      public String sayPlainTextHello() {  
        return "hello";
      }

}
```

here is my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LostLove</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
        <param-value>lostLove</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How our objects are serialized and deserialized to and from the response stream and request stream, is through [`MessageBodyWriter`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) and [`MessageBodyReader`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html).

What will happens is that a search will be done from the registry of providers, for one that can handle `JSONObject` and media type `application/json`. If one can't be found, then Jersey can't handle the request and will send out a 415 Unsupported Media Type. You should normally get an exception logged also on the server side. Not sure if you gotten a chance to view the log yet.

Jersey doesn't have any standard reader/writer for the `org.json` objects. You would have to search the web for an implementation or write one up yourself, then register it. You can read more about how to implement it [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html).

Alternatively, you could accept a String and return a String. Just construct the `JSONObject` with the string parameter, and call `JSONObject.toString()` when returning.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String post(String jsonRequest) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonRequest);
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

My suggestion instead would be to use a Data binding framework like Jackson, which can handle serializing and deserializing to and from out model objects (simple POJOs). For instance you can have a class like

```
public class Model {
    private String input;
    public String getInput() { return input; }
    public void setInput(String input) { this.input = input; }
}
```

You could have the `Model` as a method parameter

```
public ReturnType sayJsonTextHello(Model model)
```

Same for the `ReturnType`. Just create a POJO for the type you wan to return. The JSON properties are based on the [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) property names (getters/setters following the naming convention shown above).

To get this support, you can add this Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>  <!-- make sure the jersey version 
                                  matches the one you are using -->
</dependency>
```

Or if you are not using Maven, you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435), for the jars you can download independently.

**Some resources:**

- [Jersey JSON support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json)
- [Jackson documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation)

Comment: This solved my problem but now I am getting some other error =>unrecognized field (class org.json.jsonobject) not marked as ignorable. I searched on net and added JsonIgnore to method and @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) to story class but I am still getting the same error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I did not say to use JSONObject with Jackson. If you are using Jackson, use simple POJOS like my Model class. The internals of JSONObject are not in JavaBean style, which is required

Comment: See the [Jackson Tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Full_Data_Binding_.28POJO.29_Example) for en example of how your POJOs should look.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of following issue:

JAX-RS does not support default Jackson mapping conversion. So if you have the ajax request as below(Post):

```
 jQuery.ajax({
           url: "http://localhost:8081/EmailAutomated/rest/service/save",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/JSON",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            cache: false,
            context: this,
            success: function(resp){  
                 // we have the response  
                 alert("Server said123:\n '" + resp.name + "'");  
               },  
               error: function(e){  
                 alert('Error121212: ' + e);  
               }  
        });
```

and in JAX-RS controller side you need to do like below:

```
@Path("/save")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String saveDetailsUser(String userStr) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    UserDetailDTO userDetailDTO = gson.fromJson(userStr, UserDetailDTO.class);

    String vemail = userDetailDTO.getEMAIL();

    return "userDetailDTO";
}
```

**Here please make sure on parameter. service is accepting json as String not the POJO.**

Surely It will work. Thanks!

Comment: _"JAX-RS does not support default Jackson mapping conversion."_ Can you please clarify it?

Comment: It might be the problem of old versions of JAX-RS. I am using jersey 1.8.3 and specification says it does not convert json(coming from Ajax post) to POJO automatically.

Comment: [That's not accurate](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.19.1/json.html#json.pojo.approach.section): In Jersey 1.x you can enable the `JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING` and Jackson will be used to convert JSON to Java Objects and back.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But If we don't enable then Its does not make any conversion. So I answered here because might be someone else will face similar problem. Thanks Cassio!

Comment: _"I answered here because might be someone else will face similar problem."_ The OP is using Jersey 2.x instead of Jersey 1.x. See `org.glassfish.jersey` in the `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same problem when using Jersey with HTTP/2, if the client send HTTP/1.1 request,e.g. using Jersey client, then it works fine.

If I switch to Jetty HTTP2 Client to send the same content, I get 415.

The temp solution I use is the alternative described by Paul Samsotha, i.e. "accept a String and return a String", then manually deserialize the String to POJO.