# How get JSON as response in jax-rs jersey web service?

Tags: json, web-services, rest, jaxb

```
 package com.webservice.rest.jaxb;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name="employee")
    public class Employee {
    String name;
    String id;
    String location;
    float salary;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "Name [Id=" + id + ", Location=" + location
            + ", Salary=" + salary  + "]";
      }
}
```

here is My employeewebservice

```
  package com.webservice.rest.jaxb;

    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @Path("/employee")
    public class EmployeeResource {


              @GET
              @Path("/getjson")
              @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

              public Employee getJSon() {
                  Employee emp = new Employee();
                    emp.setName("Ankesh");
                    emp.setId("2096");
                    emp.setLocation("Pune_Kolkata");
                    emp.setSalary(2097868);
                    return emp;
              }

    }
```

Below Is Web .xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 
     <display-name>JaxbWithrs</display-name>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.webservice.rest.jaxb</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Iam Geting following Exception

> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,
>   type=class com.webservice.rest.jaxb.Employee, genericType=class
>   com.webservice.rest.jaxb.Employee.

Below is screenshot of my lib  directory

Please let me know if i missed anything!

Comment: You need to add a JSON provider. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30692580/2587435) for some general info.

Comment: I have used jersey-json jar .in lib then also its not working

Comment: `jersey-json` is for Jersey 1 (and it doesn't even include the required jackson dependencies). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435) for Jersey 2, if you're not using Maven.

Comment: Thank You peeskillet  it worked !! Along with jersy-json jars a  i needed following  jars jersey-media-json-jackson-2.17
    jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.2
    jackson-core-2.3.2
    jackson-databind-2.3.2
    jackson-annotations-2.3.2
    jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2
    jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2
    jersey-entity-filtering-2.17

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423776/post-to-jersey-rest-service-getting-error-415-unsupported-media-type/30424031#30424031