# Need to get Jackson JARS for Jersey

Tags: json, jackson, jersey-2.0

I am trying to pass JSON data in a post to a Jersey- based REST service. After getting HTTP 415 errors, I researched and learned that Jersey needs certain Jackson Jars in order to handle JSON.

I have been trying to find the correct Jars, but every link I am finding seems to point to places where there are a lot of README files and XML files but no Jars!

There are also several links provided here on Stack Overflow to Jackson jars. They either don't work, point to links without jars, or point to versions that will not work with Jersey v2.

Worse, I cannot find a consistent list of the Jackson jars needed for Jersey! I keep seeing different lists of Jar files that I cannot find.

Can someone please point me to the correct Jackson jars needed to provide Jersey with JSON processing??? Where can I find and download them?

Comment: You've identified the *exact* reason that questions asking us to find links to things are off-topic here - because links become dead, are moved, become outdated, etc. See the [help/on-topic] pages for more information, specifically the numbered list on that page. Good luck.

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: What Jersey version are you using? There's no such thing as "v3". If I know the version I can tell you exactly which jars you should grab.

Comment: OOPS -- Typo. It is Jersey 2.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just grab all the below Jars.

[image: jackson deps]

You can find all of them [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider). Just search for them individually.

If you are registering your providers individually, regiser

- `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` for basic JSON/POJO support.
- `JsonMappingExceptionMapper` for an `ExceptionMapper` for `JsonMappingException`
- `JsonParseExceptionMapper` for an `ExceptionMapper` for `JsonParseException`

Or if you are registering packages to be scanned, add this package

- `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json`

<sub>**Note:** The above image is from an older post. Jackson is at 2.6.1 right now. If you want, you can get the newest version. Doesn't make a difference. Just make sure all the jars are the same version</sub>

Comment: This solved the Jackson problem, but apparently not the underlying one. Apparently, just adding Jackson to a base Tomcat Jersey setup does *not* solve the HTTP Error 415 problem...

Comment: Maybe you missed the second part of the answer. You still need to register the JAX-RS provider. So unless you register the provider by package, best to include the jars into your app, and not the tomcat install. Maybe read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31991892/2587435) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30692580/2587435) for a better understanding.