# JAX-RS response.getEntity returns null after post

Tags: java, post, jax-rs

When i invoke next code:

```
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));

response.getEntity();
```

**response.getEntity()** is always null.

But when i invoke:

```
JsonObject json = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE), JsonObject.class);
```

variable **json** is not null.

I need to use first variant because i need to check response status.

Why the first code is not working?And how can i get status code then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`response.readEntity(Your.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-) to return the instance of the type you want. For example

```
String rawJson = response.readEntity(String.class);
// or
JsonObject jsonObject = response.readEntity(JsonObject.class);
```

Note that there actually needs to be a provider to handle reading that Java type and application/json. If you are using the Jersey and the JSON-P API, see [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p). Also for general information about providers, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31991892/2587435)

Comment: how about the case with large file? InputStream.class will be loaded into memory in such case...