# Java - Jersey GET request returns null; equivalent URL produces correct output in browser

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jersey

I'm currently writing a MySQL web service application which makes use of Jersey to use some GET methods, but when attempting to get the output from my webResource object, the following output is produced:

```
MySQL Response: GET http://localhost:9997/weathermap/db/xml returned a response status of 200 OK

MySQL Output as XML: null
```

I can confirm that the returned URL is **correct**. When pasting it into the browser, an output is produced that confirms execution is reaching the appropriate code block, yet the call to this using webResource methods does not.

Here is the code calling a GET request:

```
    URI url;
    try {
        url = new URI(REST_URI + XML_PATH);

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        //client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
        WebResource service = client.resource(REST_URI);

        WebResource dbService;

        dbService = service.path(XML_PATH);

        dbService = dbService.uri(url);


        System.out.println(dbService.getURI());

        System.out.println("MySQL Response: " + getResponse(dbService));
        System.out.println("MySQL Output as XML: " + getOutputAsXML(dbService));

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


private static String getResponse(WebResource service) {
    return service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ClientResponse.class).toString();
}

private static String getOutputAsXML(WebResource service) {
    return service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class);
}
```

I'm aware my dpecification of URIs/URLs is a little messy, but it's almost a carbon-copy of a working method I'm attempting to mimic.

Here is the code I'm attempting to execute:

```
@Path("/db")
public class DatabaseREST {

    public static final String propsFile = "jdbc.properties";

    @GET
    @Path("/xml") // Placeholder
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getLocationXml() {
        System.out.println("GETTING HERE"); //Spoiler: doesn't reach here
        String xml = "";

        try {
            Connection connection = getConnection();
            List<String> locations = getLocations(connection);
            xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><location>";

            for (String item: locations) {
                xml += item + " ";
            }

            xml += "</location>";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }
```

Just so you can be sure my URLs/URIs are correct, here are their definitions:

```
static final String REST_URI = "http://localhost:9997/weathermap";
static final String XML_PATH = "/db/xml";
```

I'd greatly appreciate any input at all, I've been tearing my hair out over this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs you have posted, it looks like you would only need to update the getOutputAsXML method as follows -

```
private static String getOutputAsXML(WebResource service) {
      ClientResponse response = service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);
      return response.getEntity(String.class);
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this, produces the same incorrect output. :(

Comment: Can you run it in debug mode and tell if you get a response object within this method?

Comment: I'm using eclipse and haven't used its debug mode before. Could you please quickly walk me through it?

Comment: I can confirm I have a response object. Cheers for that.

Comment: This may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104388/jax-rs-response-getentity-returns-null-after-post

Comment: The suggested method readEntity doesn't appear to be defined for a ClientResponse. Any ideas?

Comment: It may be a different version. The good news is you are receiving a response. That narrows down the problem for you. You would just need to figure out how to read the response body as xml based on the version of jersey and if you are not able to then please post another question. it may get more attention. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. If it's useful, I did just discover that attempting to access the url programmatically CAN work - it just seems to only want to do so 1% of the time.

Comment: I think it is already working for you. Check the response code to be sure from the ClientResponse. It should be 200. You just have to figure out the way to extract the xml from the response body.

Comment: The response code is reporting 200 OK, but the code it's actually supposed to run when I attempt to get data from the specified URL isn't even being reached. I have print statement in the above code (supposed to print "GETTING HERE") that only executes when I access the URL from the browser, or once in maybe 50 runs of my code.

Comment: So you mean the jersey client has some sort of caching feature? You can check this by running your code after stopping the server. And then investigate from there. As i said please create another question if you have further problems. Your original question has been answered in my opinion. Good luck. :)

Comment: Apologies, you're absolutely right. I've been examining the wrong console feed the entire time.