# How to get a single value response from java in an ajax success function

Tags: java, ajax, rest

I have my `ajax` call like this:

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["param1"].value;
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["param2"].value;
$.ajax({
        url: "./webapi/user/get?param1="+x+'&param2='+y,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: "GET",
        data:{get_param:'value'},
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
        error:function(x,y,z){
            alert(x+" "+y+" "+z);
        }
    });
```

I have my `java` function in `UserService` `class` is written like this:

```
public int getFlag(String p_param1,String p_param2) {
    int flag=0;
    try{
        dcc.connectionCall();
        stmt=dcc.con.prepareCall("{? = call function1(?,?)}");
        stmt.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.INTEGER);
        stmt.setString(2, p_param1);
        stmt.setString(3, p_param2);
        stmt.execute();
        flag = stmt.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("FLAG = "+flag+" "+p_param1+" "+p_param2);
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I have my `UserResource` `class` with the following function:

```
userService userservice = new UserService();
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public int getUser(@QueryParam("param1") String p_param1,@QueryParam("param2") String p_param2) throws SQLException{
    int flag = userservice.getUserFlag(p_param1,p_param2);
    System.out.println("FLAG= "+flag+" "+p_param1+" "+p_param2);
    return flag;
}
```

The above thing gives proper output on eclipse console. However I am unable to get the response in `ajax` `call`, which is nothing but the flag. How do I get it? I searched a lot but everything is like getting Object as a response and get it `stringified` there. But entire `json` is not needed to me. I just need the flag. Any help upon this much appreciated. I am using `Tomcat` as a server and the above assignment is for `ConnectionPooling` with `RESTful` web service.

Comment: Please show the actual response of your servlet.  For it to be legal JSON it should just be the number, and _nothing else_.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.parseJSON(data)` and get what you want. Or you will have to change your return type to cleartext (at your server-side) which does not seem feasible.

@Altinak is right, referring to [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation:

> Different types of response to $.ajax() call are subjected to
>   different kinds of pre-processing before being passed to the success
>   handler. The type of pre-processing depends by default upon the
>   Content-Type of the response, but can be set explicitly using the
>   dataType option. If the dataType option is provided, the Content-Type
>   header of the response will be disregarded.

Comment: jquery automatically parses well-formed JSON received over AJAX

Comment: @px5x2,@Alnitak as I want an integer value to be returned then what should be the dataType in `ajax` call?

Comment: @px5x2,@Alnitak, I am able to see the return values on console with error `SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.lang.Integer, genericType=int.` but the success as well as error function in ajax call doesn't show up anything.