# Not able to POST JSON data to Jersey Restful Web service

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to send JSON data to my RESTful web service. Configuration is working fine for a simple GET type. Only the issue is for POST type.

My Angular code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.pushDataToServer = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',         
        url: 'rest/Board/autoSave',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data:'{"firstName":"Syed", "lastName":"Chennai"}',
        }).success(function (data){
            $scope.status=data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error");
       });      
    };
});
```

### My Java code

```
@Path("/Board")
public class BoardAutoSaveService {

    @POST
    @Path("/autoSave")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String  autoSave(Message msg) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Calling Autosave.");
        System.out.println("First Name = "+msg.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Last Name  = "+msg.getLastName());
        return null;        
    }
}
```

### Message class

```
package com.intu;
import java.util.Date;
public class Message {

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private int age;

private Date date;

private String text;



public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

}
```

### Web.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>iNTU-1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>   
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.dao</param-value>
       </init-param>
     </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   </web-app>
```

Am I missing anything?

The error is

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.intu.Message, and Java type class com.intu.Message, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
```

Comment: did you try removing `single quotes` around data? you can send object as well not necessarily string only.

Comment: @OAD, I tried its still same

Comment: try adding POJOMappingFeature in web.xml and annotate your Message class by @XmlRootElement

Comment: @user3142222, but why? I'm not going to push XML data to my DB right? I'm just fetching the JSON data sent via Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have the default Jersey JSON providers, which require `@XmlRootElement` on your model class. You can see the available providers, one of which is the `JSON**RootElement**Provider`

```
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
```

This provider is used to (de)serialize classes annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.

If you have the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

then it should also pull in the Jackson provider, which doesn't require `@XmlRootElement`, but you still need to configure Jersey to use Jackson instead of its default provider. To configure it you need to add this to your web.xml Jersey servlet configuration, as seen [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#json.pojo.approach.section)

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Or if you are not using a web.xml, add the following inside your `ResourceConfig` subclass constructor

```
public class AppConfig extends PackagesResourceConfig{

    public AppConfig() {
        getProperties().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Peekskilet. I'm not using Maven project.  What should I do?

Comment: Which JAR should I need to include?

Comment: You can look at the image from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31991892/2587435)

Comment: Then you need to register the `JacksonJsonProvider`. You can just add this package (`com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json`) to the list of packages to scan, in your web.xml

Comment: i.e. `<param-value>com.dao,com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json</param-value>`

Comment: If you do it this way, you can ignore all that stuff about the `POJOMappingFeature`. It will not be required

Comment: It worked when I included Jackson JAR's. Should I add this tag in web.xml too?

Comment: Not exactly sure what jars you added, so I am not sure how you got it working. But if it's working, I would say you don't need it.

Comment: Cool. I added Jackson-core-asl-1.9.2, jackson-jaxrs, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2 & jackson-xc-1.9.2.