# REST : Reading post body in jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am not able to read json data in post.  So far I have been successful is reading string data in get method. Now i am working on POST where I am sending following JSON in body :

{"name": "myname","address":"myaddress"}

I am also sending content-type : application/json header information in the request.

**I have downloaded jersey moxy jar and corresponding dependencies.** My model class is as following :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Mymodel{
@XMLElement
public String name;
@XMLElement
public String address;
}
```

following is the extract of the resource method

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.Application_JSON)
public Resource mymethod(Mymodel mode){
System.out.println(mode.name);
}
```

Am i missing something ? **Error I am getting is that media type is not supported(415 Unsupported Media Type)**. 
I don't have anything related to json in the web.xml.

As i mentioned in my post above ,I am using jersey moxy jar which actually supports json application type in jersey. So my understanding is that as suggested adding "jersey-media-json-jackson" jar will not add any value, **or I need both jackson and moxy jar ?**

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30692221/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet: Thanks a lot for help. Please see my updated question, I am already using moxy jar for that purpose, do i still need jackson jar ?

Comment: No. Add an `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` and print the stacktrace. If it's a problem with the MOXy deserialization, you should see an exception.

Comment: **To closers:** Please don't close as a duplicate (this is not a duplicate as the OP already has a provider)

Comment: You can also try and add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)` or if that doesn't work `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on top of `Mymodel`

Comment: You only downloaded one MOXy jar? Nothing else with it?

Comment: Hello All, Problem is solved, i do not know the exact reason , but i had two jars in my classpath, gson and moxy, i removed gson from my class path and it started working,  i saw apache logs, there was nothing mentioned there, but thanks @peeskillet