# Jersey application - 415 unsupported media type

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jersey

I have jersey application and i could not make form submit success. I get 415 unsupported media type error.

**AngularJs:**

```
$http.put(url, frmData, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: frmData
    });
```

**Java:**

```
@PUT
@Path("/submitform")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void saveForm(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                     PojoClass pojoClass) {

}
```

I get 415 unsupported media type error.

Is there anywhere I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Without some tweeking, Jersey doesn't know how to convert `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data into a POJO. The following are what it knows

```
public Response post(javax.ws.rs.core.Form form)

public Response post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> form)

public Response post(@FormParam("key1") key1, @FormParam("key2") String key)
```

If you want to use a POJO, you can annotate the POJO parameter with `@BeanParam`, and annotate the POJO fields with `@FormParam`

```
public class POJO {
    @FormParam("key1")
    private String key1;
    @FormParam("key2")
    private String key2;
    // getters/setters
}

public Response pose(@BeanParam POJO pojo)
```

If you are using Angular though, you might as well use JSON, as that's the default behavior. You may want to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692580/2587435), if you want to work with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add 
   `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` in your saveFormMethod
2. Instead of mapping `pojoClass` directly as a input parameter, change input parameter as a `string` and then use `gson` library to convert string back to actual POJO object.