# REST API is unable to work in JSON format

Tags: java, json, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am new to developing `REST API` with Java. I made a very simple one using the `mkyong` tutorials, where it only says "hello". I am using Apache Tomcat.

Now I am trying to develop a one where it will return the `JSON` objects. I am attempting the example here - http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/. Some of the code are changed (ex: package name).Below is my code.

**Track.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
public class Track {

    String title;
    String singer;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSinger() {
        return singer;
    }

    public void setSinger(String singer) {
        this.singer = singer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track [title=" + title + ", singer=" + singer + "]";
    }

}
```

**JsonService.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JsonService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return track;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
        
    }
    
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>NewServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
     <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param> 
      </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NewServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

My application is **not** a `marven` project. So the added libraries are below.

[image]

I tested the application with the below URL.

`http://localhost:8080/RESTFUL_API_SAMPLE/rest/json/metallica/get`

All I got is the below page

[image]

Any idea about why I am not getting the expected result?

Comment: please post log or some error message

Comment: Try to debug, put a breakpoint at `Track track = new Track();`. Also, you are retunirng a `Track` object, you need to return a JSONObject.

Comment: Not sure the reason for the error, but you don't have any JSON support currently. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet: Please provide your comment as an answer. It solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you don't have any JSON/POJO support. The `jersey-json` jar and the `POJOMappingFeature` configuration in your web.xml is for Jersey 1.x, which won't work for Jersey 2.x. For all the jars you need for Jersey 2.x support, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435).