# Issue marshalling generic with Moxy and JerseyClient2

Tags: java, generics, jersey-2.0, moxy, jersey-client

The following code uses the Jersey2 client (v 2.22.2) with the built-in Moxy JSON support. I am trying to marshal a generified wrapper class into JSON. As you can see below the `json` property isn't unmarshalling as intended.

When I change the type for the `json` property to `Service` and 'ungenerify' the class everything works as intended but I would prefer to be able to do this with generics so I don't have to create a bunch of these wrapper classes for each type that needs to be wrapped in this fashion.

JSONWrapper.java

```
public class JSONWrapper<T> implements Serializable {
  private T json;

  public T getJson() { return this.json; }
  public void setJson (T payload) { this.json = payload; }

  public JSONWrapper() {}
}
```

Service.java

```
public class Service implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

MyClient.java

```
public class MyClient {
  private Client jerseyClient;

  public void createService(Service item) {
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = buildRequest(SERVICE_PATH);
    JSONWrapper<Service> wrapper = new JSONWrapper<>();
    wrapper.setJson(item);
    final Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(wrapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
  }

  public MyClient() {
     this.jerseryClient = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyClient myClient = new MyClient();
     Service myService = new Service();
     myService.setName("foo");
     myClient.createService(myService);
  }
}
```

With the logging filter turned on I am seeing that Moxy's marshalling of things looks like so:

> {"json":"com.baz.Service@5674e1f2"}

When I want it to look like so

> {"json":"{"name": "foo"}"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of type erasure, the generic type is wiped out at runtime, so MOXy doesn't know the generic type and just spits out its `toString`. This is one of the limitations of using MOXy (it relies on some JAXB functionality). To get around this, JAX-RS has the [`GenericEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html) that let's us wrap the generic type, so it's known to serializers.

```
JsonWrapper<Service> service = new JsonWrapper<>();
user.setJson(new Service("blah"));
GenericEntity<JsonWrapper<Service>> entity 
        = new GenericEntity<JsonWrapper<Service>>(service){};
Response response = target("test").request().post(Entity.json(entity));
```

From what I just tested with MOXy, for some reason it spits out an extra `"type":"service"` property in the JSON. I am not completely sure why. I haven't used MOXy in a while. I've had too many problems with it. Personally, I'd recommend switching over to Jackson. With Jackson you will not have this type problem. You could get away with *not* using `GenericEntity`, and it will work out the box. If you're using Maven, just add the following dependency and remove MOXy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435).

Comment: Thanks, I had played around with GenericEntity but this works perfectly.