# Rest Webservice Returns 415 unsupported media Type.

Tags: rest, jersey, tomcat7, http-status-code-415

Before you go ahead and mark it as duplicate, please note, this is not a duplicate question. I have checked all the previously accepted answers and I added the following with no help.

```
@Produces("application/json"), @Consumes("application/json")
```

which had no effect. and I have tried

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON),@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Here is my code and I wonder where i'm going wrong in this particular case.

```
@Path("/URLSigner")
public class UrlSigner {
    @Path("/sign")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getSignedURL(UrlSignerRequest usRequest) {
        String file_key = "";
        SignURLResponse SUresponse = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        if(!( file_key = checkIfObjectExistsInS3(usRequest.getObject_name())).startsWith("FILE")) {
            SUresponse = new SignURLResponse(getURLSigned(file_key), usRequest.getObject_name(), sdf.format(getExpiryDate()));

        }else {
            SUresponse = new SignURLResponse(file_key, usRequest.getObject_name(), "URL Not generated");
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(SUresponse).build();
    }
```

My Request class looks like this.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class UrlSignerRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String object_name;

    public String getObject_name() {return object_name;} 

    public String toString() {
        return "SignURLRequest [ "+ "object_name=" + object_name +"]";
    }
}
```

URL: http://localhost:9999/MyRestApi/rest/URLSigner/sign

input:

```
{
  "object_name": "file1.xml"
}
```

Comment: Did you add a JSON provider? This should have been explained in whatever "non-duplicates" you're referring to.

Comment: I have a "jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.0.0.jar" and "gson-2.3.1.jar". Guess if that's all or if I have add anything else.

Comment: One jar isn't enough... http://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435

Comment: Thank you so much @peeskillet I had all the jars but I had someother version of the same jar for another dependency. . I had no idea of this dependency conflict until you mentioned. Thank you once again.