# Jersey bean validation responding 415 unsupported media type

Tags: jersey

I am trying to validate a json request from client using bean validation. Here is my resource class

```
@Path("/test")
public class Tester {

public Tester(){

}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response test(@Valid Test test) throws ConstraintViolationException{

    return Response.status(200).entity("hello world")
 }

}
```

and here is my Test class

```
public class Test {

public Test(){

}

@NotNull(message="test cannot be empty")
private String test;

public String getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(String test) {
    this.test = test;
}
}
```

and everytime i send a request from client it responds `415 unsupported media type` can anybody please help? i used jersey-bean-validation-2.25.1 
Thanx!!!

Comment: And it works when you remove the bean validation?

Comment: Actually i just noticed i doesn't work even when i remove the bean validation. any thought why that can be?

Comment: You probably just need to add a JSON provider. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423776/post-to-jersey-rest-service-getting-error-415-unsupported-media-type/30424031#30424031)

Comment: Thanx @peeskillet addin JSON provider solved the problem