# MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException : I don't know how retrieve data send

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I explain my problem. I send a Object who comes from my class User. I send it from my website to my restful service. But I try to have it and all types that I try in my params are not valide or null :

**SEND Class:**

```
   public String update() {
    try {
        if(mdpVerification.equals(utilisateur.getMotDePasse())){
        clientRest.setPath("user");
        clientRest.putEntity(SessionBeanEFPlanning.getAdministrateur().getLogin()
                , SessionBeanEFPlanning.getAdministrateur().getMotDePasse(), utilisateur, utilisateur.getId());
        SessionBeanEFPlanning.displayFacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "L'utilisateur a été modifié avec succès!");
        setUtilisateur(null);
        setUtilisateurs(null);
        super.getUtilisateurs();
        return "/utilisateurs/index?faces-redirect=true";
        }else{
        SessionBeanEFPlanning.displayFacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Les mot de passes ne concordent pas !");    
        return "/utilisateur/edit?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    } catch (serverIllegalStateException exception) {
        String message = "";
        if (exception.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("erreur : pseudo identique")) {
            message = "Ce pseudo est déjà attribué !";
        } else if (exception.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("erreur : email identique")) {
            message = "Cet email est déjà attribué !";
        } else {
            message = exception.toString();
        }
        SessionBeanEFPlanning.displayFacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message);
        return "/utilisateurs/edit?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

I have already see if my Object was null and it was not ! I give you the class how send informations :

```
public Object putEntity(String login, String password, Utilisateur JsonObject,  Long id) {
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(URI_REST_SERVICE)
            .path(URI_PATH)
            .path(Long.toString(id))
            .queryParam("login", login)
            .queryParam("password", password);
    System.out.println(webTarget);
    return super.<Utilisateur>putEntity(webTarget, JsonObject, new GenericType<Utilisateur>() {
    });
}
```

And its interface :

```
protected <T> T putEntity(WebTarget webTarget, T entity, GenericType genericType) {
    Response response = put(webTarget, entity);
    checkStatus200(response);
    return (T) response.readEntity(genericType);
}
```

Now I give you the receive class :

```
@PUT
@Path("/{id : \\d+}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateUser(@QueryParam("login") String login,
        @QueryParam("password") String password,@PathParam("id") long id, JsonArray  utilisateur) {
    try {
        System.out.println(utilisateur);
        if (utilisateur != null) {
           // mapper.update(utilisateur);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(utilisateur).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(
                    new MessageServiceErreur("Erreur utilisateur NULL")).build();
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateMessage exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(
                new MessageServiceErreur(exception.toString())).build();
    } 

}
```

And like the title said  I have this error from my tomcat log ::

```
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=interface javax.json.JsonArray, genericType=interface javax.json.JsonArray.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
    ... 41 more
```

My question is : How can I receive the information correctly ?

**NEW ERROR :**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class javax.json.JsonObject, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class javax.json.JsonValue]]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:268)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:144)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:381)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._findRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:1380)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1228)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:677)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:777)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**LOG JERSEY  :**

```
HTTP REQUEST : User: unknown - Path: /user - Header: {accept=[application/json], user-agent=[Jersey/2.10.4 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_77)], host=[localhost:8082], connection=[keep-alive]} - Entity: 

HTTP RESPONSE : Header: {Content-Type=[application/json]} - Entity: [EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@6a277cb, EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@1fe07c0b]
HTTP REQUEST : User: unknown - Path: /user - Header: {accept=[application/json], user-agent=[Jersey/2.10.4 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_77)], host=[localhost:8082], connection=[keep-alive]} - Entity: 

HTTP RESPONSE : Header: {Content-Type=[application/json]} - Entity: [EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@73fd68e9, EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@4d012aaf]
HTTP REQUEST : User: unknown - Path: /user/4601 - Header: {accept=[application/json], content-type=[application/json], user-agent=[Jersey/2.10.4 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_77)], host=[localhost:8082], connection=[keep-alive], content-length=[109]} - Entity: {"id":4601,"login":"Scadra","motDePasse":"","nom":"Colart","prenom":"Pierre","typeUtilisateur":"RESPONSABLE"}

HTTP RESPONSE : Header: {Content-Type=[application/json]} - Entity: EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@1ac66ff1
HTTP REQUEST : User: unknown - Path: /user - Header: {accept=[application/json], user-agent=[Jersey/2.10.4 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_77)], host=[localhost:8082], connection=[keep-alive]} - Entity: 

HTTP RESPONSE : Header: {Content-Type=[application/json]} - Entity: [EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@617845f2, EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@70eb5f1a]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that it can't deserialize the income JSON into a `JsonArray`.

> *"How can I receive the information correctly ?"*

1. Use a POJO instead of `JsonArray` as the method parameter.
2. Make sure you have a [Json Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435)

**Note:** The previous link is for JSON/POJO support. If you want to stick with using the `Javax.json` classes (i.e. the `JsonArray`), you can also just include the following dependency (which has support for JSON-P)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This is all explained in [Jersey docs: Support for Common Media Type Representations](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html)

Comment: thank for your reply, I have already Jar in my project :) the question is : why it does not work :)

Comment: I understand your response but I have an other error, I edited my post

Comment: Because you're trying to use Jackson with the JSON-P (javax.json) classes.  If you want to use Jackson, then use POJOS. If you want to continue using the JSON-P classes, then you need to use the dependency in my post.

Comment: ok but I don't want to use it, I juste want to have my user in rest.

Comment: how can I do it without jackson I know it is possible

Comment: As you can see I send Object when do :     public Response updateUser(@QueryParam("login") String login,
            @QueryParam("password") String password,@PathParam("id") long id, Utilisateur utilisateur) { I have not error but utilisateur is null

Comment: it is very strange perhaps may I create new question?

Comment: Do some logging. Is there even any data in the request body? Maybe there is nothing. Look at the Jersey docs for logging. There is a logging feature you can add to both the client and the server so you can see the body. https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html

Comment: first thank for your help I have like result in log :

Comment: Thank's to your help